# Find and replace strings in files in a given date range by filename

Tags: powershell, date-range, powershell-cmdlet

A nice tough one for you all. I'm trying to find and replace a given string in a bunch of files. The files have a date stamp in the file name i.e. `YYYY_MM_DD_file.txt`

I wish to search and replace within a date range for these files and then replace a string I define, I cannot use date modified as the date range, I must rely on the stamp in the filename.

So far I set my date range in WPF text fields:

```
$Filename = $Filenamebox.text
$startdate = [datetime] $startdatetext.text
$enddate = [datetime] $enddatetext.Text
$NewFilenamereal = $Newfilename.Text

$array = 
   do {
   $startdate.ToString('yyyy_MM_dd*')
   $startdate = $startdate.AddDays(1)
  }

until ($startdate -gt [datetime] $enddate)


$files1 = $array | foreach-object {"C:\Users\michael.lawton\Desktop\KGB\Test folder\$_"}

write-host $files1
```

I then get child items using the `$files1` array I have created as a search mask for the files in the date range and find all matches. Store this in a variable and replace the string `$filename` with the new string `$Newfilenamereal`.

```
$Matches1 = get-childitem $files1 | select-string $Filename | foreach-object    {$_ -replace $Filename,$Newfilenamereal} | out-string

write-host $Matches1
```

However I cannot work out how to overwrite what has been found and replaced in the `$Matches1` variable to the original files. I have tried `set-content`, however this will simply either erase everything I have in the date stamped files or cannot understand the `$files1` array as a file path.

So my question to you lovely people is how do I write what I have replaced in the environment to the actual files?

Comment: do you want to rename the file?

Comment: No, only the matching strings found in the matching files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just retrieve the file content using the `Get-Content` cmdlet and replace the string. Finally write it back using the `Set-Content` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem $files1 | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ | Get-Content -Raw) -replace $Filename,$Newfilenamereal | 
        Set-Content -Path $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much. Can you please explain step by step? I don't fully understand it

Comment: Sorry, writing from my Phone. The First get-childitem cmdlet is probably obsolete. So I iterate over the files and load the content using the get-content cmdlet. Then using -replace on the content for the replacement. Finally the new content gets piped to the set-content cmdlet to write it back